# Netbeans Entity classes from database wizard fails

Tags: netbeans

My setup:

- Netbeans 16 on windows 11
- Mysql server 8
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40354 (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
- Payara server 5.2 configured in Netbeans.

I have a legacy web application which uses Jdbc resources and connection pools defined in **domain.xml** inside Payara.

When I deploy the application it works correctly and can access the data in Mysql.
I need to add some new entities and I launch *Entity classes from database wizard* but it fails.
I had weird problems with that wizard in the past months but since then I changed computer reinstalling everything from scratch and the wizard doesn't work any more.

At **step 2** I select a datasource which comes from Payara's **domain.xml** and an error is immediately reported:

```
Unable to find driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource. Register this driver in databases tab
```

I think it refers to Tab Services, Databases tree node, drivers. Unfortunately I cannot add class **MysqlDataSource** there because it only accepts driver classes.
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found two possible workarounds.

- Temporarily remove the Payara server from Netbeans.
  Now the Datasource select box is not populated from **domain.xml**
  so you can finally choose a database connection already defined inside Netbeans or create a new one with "New datasource..."
- Open **domain.xml**, search for the Jdbc connection pool you are going to use and add valid *URL* and *driverClass* properties